# Как вытащить аватарку steam?

Tags: php, html, mysql, steam-web-api

Без авторизации можно вытащить картинку пользователя ?

То есть пользователь зарегестрирован на сайте.И имеет уже стим ид.

Можно ли вытащить стим аватарку по его стим ид? то есть он не будет делать вход на стим.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашол способ кому надо:

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX - API KEY

```
$String =        file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&steamids='.$friend[steam_id].'");

  $new = $String; //Текст, который читается... 
  $newcr = ''; //Строка, которая будет выводится... 

$newm = explode('",', $new); //Делим текст на слова... 
$space = ' '; //А этим пробелом можно словать соединять... А ещё это можно будет поменять на любой другой символ... 

$newcr = $newcr.$space.$newm[4]; //И пихаем все слова в одну строку... 

$str = $newcr;
$str = str_replace(array('"avatarmedium": "'), '', $str);
   $mail = trim(strrchr($str, ' '));

echo '<img src='.$mail.'></img>';
```